# Ios :: dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIAlertAction

Tags: ios7, xcode6, ios8.3

I have an app which works fine with iOS sdk 8.3 and Xcode 6. but when i check backward compatibility with iOS sdks 7.1 and 7.1 simulator it fails.

App crashes with following error

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIAlertAction
Referenced from: /Users/apogaeis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F48B2D65-9EE8-4737-A0CE-2882D105C6C9/data/Applications/25B9DCDE-4BC6-4568-8EBE-3474FE559CBC/AppName.app/AppName
Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
in /Users/apogaeis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F48B2D65-9EE8-4737-A0CE-2882D105C6C9/data/Applications/25B9DCDE-4BC6-4568-8EBE-3474FE559CBC/AppName.app/AppName
```

Please suggest to resolve the issue.

How can i make it work for all the iOS versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case, UIKit.Framework had to be marked Optional rather than Required now my app works fine....